# Is it appropriate to ask manager or HR about the salary range of my salary band?

Tags: salary, new-zealand

I want to get an overall view of the salary ceiling of my salary band. This is purely for my own reference. I do not plan to ask for a raise yet.

Is it appropriate to ask about the salary range to my manager or HR?

Comment: In my (limited) experience, most places that have salary bands publish the range of numbers internally. I guess your company doesn't? Is that what you're asking, for the numbers? Do you have any specific reason for asking - in particular are you really asking for a raise, and likely to give them that impression? Broadly I expect it's fine to ask though.

Comment: @Rup, I am asking because I want to get an overall view of the salary ceiling, purely for my own reference. I am not planning to ask for a raise, yet.

Comment: What country and industry are you in? This may have a bearing on what is considered appropriate.

Comment: @user16259, New Zealand

Comment: @dwizum You are correct about the *answer* to the question being company specific. However, the question asked here is "is it appropriate to ask this question?", not "what is the answer to this question?". Your last sentence also seems to answer the question (correctly, IMHO).

Comment: @MaskedMan yes, I thought about that subtlety. Sometimes, when people say, "is it appropriate" I wonder if they're really meaning, "will I get an answer or will I get laughed at?" I was trying to address "will I get an answer" which is company specific. This question is so sparse on details it's hard to address with a specific answer, hence the comment.

Comment: @dwizum Indeed, I totally understand what you had in mind, because I was about to post that as an answer "you can ask, but you will probably not get an answer".

Comment: @YuZhang I moved some of the details from your comments into the question, and it seems what you are actually looking for is the salary *range* for your current salary band, so I have edited that in. If you have any more details to add, or you don't agree with my changes, please [edit] the post accordingly.

Comment: If you have formal bands set by are they actually published?

Comment: @MaskedMan, thanks for the editing, your editing made my question clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is appropriate to ask about the salary band you are in. It is also useful to know what you have to do to go to the next salary band.

If they keep it confidential, then that is also an important thing to know.

One natural place to bring it up is during a annual review. In several of the companies I have worked for, looking out at potential opportunities for growth or advancement was a required part of the process.

Even if the company is transparent about salary ranges, your manager may get concerned that too many questions about promotions and salary bands may be a sign that you want to leave.

Comment: Its also useful when applying to external jobs as its help you negotiate eg civil service grades

Answer (score 2):

Your specific question was,

> Is appropriate to ask for information about my salary band within the company?

It can certainly be *appropriate* to ask in the right setting. Most employers are interested in helping employees develop and progress in their career; understanding your "band" and how the salary range it implies plays into your future plans can be a natural and appropriate part of that conversation - ie as part of an annual performance review or other goal-setting discussion.

Outside that framework, it can also be *appropriate* as it's a natural curiosity to want to understand - although, it may cause the employer to wonder if you asking that question was a hint that you may want to leave soon (and you're trying to understand your future salary cap at the current employer in order to compare it to offers from other employers). Hence, if you do ask outside a performance review setting, it may be *most appropriate* to do so with some framework - for instance, tell the employer you're trying to plan your future at the company and want to understand how raises/advances typically work.

All that said, a question related to yours is,

> If I ask my employer for my salary band, will I get an answer?

And that is hard for us to answer, since it is highly company-specific. Some employers publish this information to all employees (or even to the general public). Others will only tell you the range for your current band, while others keep it entirely private and won't even tell you the range for your own band.

All that said, it's always a good idea to understand your own financial future, so the key here is, **start having a discussion with your manager or HR about your future - how raises work, what band you're in, what the company does to encourage growth (could be financial compensation or otherwise), and so on.**